# How can I display the featured image in this shortcode pulling from ACF fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode, wordpress-featured-image

I'm using the following shortcode which pulls from an ACF post object field and works to display post titles as links in a list:

```
function related_for_products( $atts ) {
global $post;
$related = get_field('product_related');
$html = '';
if( $related ) {
    $html .= '<ul>';
    foreach( $related as $option ) {
        $permalink = get_permalink( $option->ID );
        $title = get_the_title( $option->ID );
        $html .= '<li><a href="'. esc_url( $permalink ) . '">' . esc_html( $title ) . '</a></li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
}
return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'related', 'related_for_products' );
```

How can I add the post featured image to the link element so both the title and the image display, and both link to the post? I've tried the following and variations but I must be getting my syntax wrong as I either get an empty image element or nothing at all.

```
function related_for_products( $atts ) {
global $post;
$related = get_field('product_related');
$html = '';
if( $related ) {
    $html .= '<ul>';
    foreach( $related as $option ) {
        $permalink = get_permalink( $option->ID );
        $title = get_the_title( $option->ID );
        $featured = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $option->ID );
        $html .= '<li><a href="'. esc_url( $permalink ) . '">' . esc_html( $title ) . ' <img src="'. esc_url( $featured ) . '"></a></li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
 }
 return $html;
 }
 add_shortcode( 'related', 'related_for_products' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try using

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($option->ID, "full")
```

instead. This will give you the full image with source set, etc.

it might look something like this:

```
$html .= '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $permalink ) . '"><h3>' . esc_html( $title ) . '</h3>' . $featured  . '</a></li>';
```

Maybe view the actual HTML that gets output (inspector or view-source) and you will be able to see why your image was empty.

lastly, (if you haven't already) use var_dump($featured); so you can see exactly what is being returned.